# Can I emulate application upgrade with ADB?

Tags: android, adb

Can I emulate application upgrade with ADB?

When I do `adb install` I have to delete the previous version first, if already installed.

If it is not possible to emulate app upgrade with ADB what could be the easiest way to emulate it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `adb install -r <apk path>` it keeps the data and re-installs the apk

Other available options for `adb install`:

> -l: Install the package with forward lock.
>
> -r: Reinstall an exisiting app, keeping its data.
>
> -t: Allow test APKs to be installed.
>
> -i : Specify the installer package name.
>
> -s: Install package on the shared mass storage (such as sdcard).
>
> -f: Install package on the internal system memory.
>
> -d: Allow version code downgrade.