# The differnce betwteen incremental upgrade a app from my server and from application market

Tags: android

when I incremental  upgrade a app from my server ,   my app download a patch ,  merge with the old apk，then my app  get a new apk， and my app's activity  call install to install it . but when I   incremental  upgrade a app
from    application market，  and my app keep closed， will  application market do the merge for me ?  or It will open my app to let my app  finish the merge (merge the old apk and the patch to the newest apk) ?

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "my app download a patch, merge with old apk". What specifically is getting "patched" if you are downloading a new apk.

Comment: thanks, for example, someone developed  a  app:  twitter  1.0 apk  and put it to applicaton market a year ago,it 's 200M  ,now  develop a new version : twitter 2.0，but twitter 2.0 is too big,it's 300M,  so decide to make a patch by Smart App Updates,now get a patch ,is only 110M, then  put it to the application market， then the phone download the patch ,then on the phone who will merge the  twitter  1.0 (200M)  and patch(110M )  to  twitter 2.0 apk ?  It 's the application market client itsself    ?  or the application market client will start twitter  1.0 and let twitter  1.0 to merge it ?

Comment: Your example isn't correct as the Google Play Store has a app size limit of [150MB](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859152?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmaximum-size-limit), and the original v1 apk is stored on the phone. When an app is updated from v1 the old data is preserved, so it is within the v2 code that any data migration needs to take place. How that v2 code is deployed can either be a [traditional apk update which can be tested via adb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20780293/295004) or the Play Store patch applied the stored apk on the phone.

Comment: For apps (like games) that are bigger than the 150MB limit, Google has [Play Asset Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery) and [Play Feature Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery) . Related: [App update process](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140333/3573)